# Manually chosen rendition is not taking effect on the brightcove player

Tags: brightcove

I'm changing the video rendition using the `setRenditionSelectionCallback` as explained here http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/selecting-multi-bitrate-streaming-renditions. But seems like the rendition I choose is never being displayed, even when in the brightcove debugger I see messages like:

`Attempting to change rendition that the player expects to play from (110000b/s, 400x224) to (800000b/s, 640x360)`

`New rendition chosen from external rendition algorithm.`

Is there anything else that should be done for update the rendition that is being displayed? Or is it a know issue? I'm only updating the rendition index in the `setRenditionSelectionCallback` callback.

Thanks in advance for any help here! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to change dynamically the rendition in a progressive download account. In this kind of accounts the rendition selection is only possible at the very start.

It is possible to force a rendition change with a progressive account by using a different method, but that will restart playback (and download) from the beginning again. There's an existing plugin doing that: https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/Rendition-Selector-Plugin.